# Can Initialization-on-demand holder Idiom result in a partially created object?

Tags: java, singleton

```
 class SingletonImpl{

        private SingletonImpl() {
            /*
             *  time consuming operation 
             */
        }

        private static class SingletonHolder {
            private static final SingletonImpl INSTANCCE = new SingletonImpl();
        }

        public static SingletonImpl getInstance(){
            return SingletonHolder.INSTANCCE;
        }
    }
```

Will there be any chance that we may get half cooked(not fully initialized) object to INSTANCE variable ?

Comment: This is present in "Item 71" of *Effective Java (2nd Edition)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) article on Intitialization-on-demand holder idiom :

> Since the class initialization phase is guaranteed by the JLS to be serial, i.e., non-concurrent, no further synchronization is required in the static getInstance method during loading and initialization. And since the initialization phase writes the static variable INSTANCE in a serial operation, all subsequent concurrent invocations of the getInstance will return the same correctly initialized INSTANCE without incurring any additional synchronization overhead

The answer is **No**. This is because of the statement "*the initialization phase writes the static variable INSTANCE in a serial operation*". That is, while one thread has called `getInstance`, the call to `getinstance` from another thread will wait until `SingletonHolder` is completely loaded. For `SingletonHolder` to be completely loaded, `INSTANCE` will have to be created. Once `SingletonHolder` has been loaded, any subsequent calls to `getInstance` will simply return `INSTANCE` with no `synchronization` overhead.

The locking mechanism used while loading classes is described in detail in the [Section 12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) of the JLS.

Comment: I too expected the same but i was getting error(initialization/linkage error) while running unit test case. When used updated volatile variable at the end of the constructor then stopped getting error. So created confusion and thought of reordering as that of DCL.

Comment: @javaq I don't think the `linkage` error indicates that `INSTANCE` is getting partially created. So the answer is still  a *No*. `INSTANCE` can't be half cooked. If your question is about the `linkage` error, you should post a new question with relevant code.